# Django Image should be displayed but isnt

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't understand why the image isn't being displayed,

HTML

```
 <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3">
     <div class="features-icons-icon d-flex">
         <img src="{{ x.pic.url }}">
     </div>
```

model

```
class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='item name...')
desc = models.TextField(default='Description....')
pic = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='item_pics')
```

views

```
def index(request):
itemList = Item.objects.all()
return render(request, 'main/items.html', {'itemlist': itemList})
```

settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: "GET /media/item_pics/dlphtml.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6509
getting that ^^^

Comment: What {{ x.pic.url }} is referring at? Add it like <p>{{ x.pic.url }}</p> to know the path. And see if it matches to the correct image path.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show the result you get if you think it's relevant, don't add as a comment

Comment: look in your file manager: is the file in /media/item_pics/ inside your project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not added the media url in urlpatterns.

Change the url.py in project as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Refer the django documentation for more Explanations [Django media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)